# D3 v4 quadtree root is returning undefined

Tags: d3.js

I'm using D3 v4 and can't get quadtree to work. It keeps returning undefined for the root. I don't think it likes the data I'm giving it.

```
    const Nodes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Nodes.push({
    radius: 5,
    x: Math.random() * 500,
    y: Math.random() * 500,
    velocityX: Math.random(),
    velocityY: Math.random()
  });
}

collide() {
  var quadtree = d3.quadtree().extent([
    [
      0, 0
    ],
    [1500, 1000]
  ]).addAll(Nodes);

  console.log(quadtree);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at any given object in your `Nodes` array:

```
[{
    radius: 5,
    x: 301.25792388143293,
    y: 35.626900264457696,
    velocityX: 0.43542026096574715,
    velocityY: 0.03662733324854717
}]
```

As you can see, the `x` and `y` coordinates are defined in properties with `"x"` and `"y"` as key.

However, this is the default function for the `x` coordinate in `d3.quadtree`:

```
function x(d) {
    return d[0];
}
```

And for the `y` coordinate:

```
function y(d) {
    return d[1];
}
```

As you can see, those functions won't work with your object structure.

**Solution**:

Set the `x` and `y` coordinates according to your object:

```
var quadtree = d3.quadtree()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.x
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.y
    })
```

Here is your code with that change, check the console:

```js
const Nodes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Nodes.push({
    radius: 5,
    x: Math.random() * 500,
    y: Math.random() * 500,
    velocityX: Math.random(),
    velocityY: Math.random()
  });
}

var quadtree = d3.quadtree().extent([
    [
      0, 0
    ],
    [1500, 1000]
  ]).x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .addAll(Nodes);

console.log(quadtree);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```